# is there any way that i can print ajax success response without using alert

Tags: javascript, php

is there any way that i can print ajax success response without using alert? Because alert won't display full data, i need to go through my full html response data. alert display only a part of it.

```js
$.ajax({
        method :'GET',
        url: baseUrl+'ajaxcontroller/LoadData_To_View',
        success:function(data){
        $('#item').html(data);
        alert(data);
        },
        complete: function(){
        $('#loadingImage2').hide();
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){alert(thrownError);}
        });
```

Comment: Why not? Just take a div in DOM and set text in that div.

Comment: In your succes function, at the beginning, put this line: `console.log(data);` and show what it prints. Maybe your url is wrong

Comment: @Damian Peralta : Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways 
you can print in developer console like in Chrome.
or 
Print it in a Div

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "url", success: function(result){

    // Print in Chrome Console
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    // In a div
        $("#div1").html(JSON.stringify(result));
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a empty div and set the response as html using jQuery

```
<div id="id"></div>

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data_handler.php",
        data: dataString,                   
        cache: true,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#DivID").html(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks , but please check my code, i have already done that, problem is it won't display anything i think there is a problem within my  ajaxcontroller/LoadData_To_View.

Comment: yes, it returns, but only a half of it. i think somewhere in the middle of  something happens ajaxcontroller/LoadData_To_View and it won't display any errors

Answer (score 0):

For displaying data you can use `console.log(data)` and check it in pressing `ctrl + shift + I` and chose console you will see your data there, also you can make `<div id='dump'></div>` somewhere in your page and print your message there like this `$('#dump').html(data);` if you are using jquery else use another access point to `id`

Comment: you have to make new route and dump your session there after that just make ajax on this route

Answer (score 0):

instead of alert you can also use console.log() and just open console in your browser, so that you can check it without alert

Answer (score 0):

Yes there any way that you can print ajax success response without using alert You can use console.log(); method

then your answer will be displayed in console

hope this answer will work.